# How to test if a Range is blank?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a college exercise and I need to check if some specific cells are blank. If they are blank, I need to write something in them. I've tried to make one program, but it did not worked, showing me the error: 13.

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

If Range("a1:e1").Value = "" Then
   Range("a1:e1") = "x"
End If

End Sub
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

If a range contains 1 cell then its `.Value` property returns a single scalar value.
However, If a range contains multiple cells then its `.Value` property returns an Array.
You could iterate over all the cells in the range to see if they are all empty.  Alternatively, you could use `WorksheetFunction.CountBlank` to see if the number of blanks in the range matches the number of cells in the range.

```
With Range("a1:e1")
    If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Cells) = .Cells.Count Then
       Range("a1:e1") = "x"
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you want to do in case one cell in this range is not empty.

Since the case where you want to fill the cells **if they are all blank** has been already covered, I will cover the case where you want to check if there are any blank cells in a range and if yes then fill them.

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("A1:E1").Cells
    If cell.Value = "" Then
        cell.Value = "x"
    End If
Next cell
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `WorksheetFunction.CountA`. It counts non empty cells. Like this:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("a1:e1")) = 0 Then
   Range("a1:e1") = "x"
End If
```

It does the same as TinMan's code. But the check is differend.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this code:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:E1")
    ' if we come upon non-empty cell we exit sub and do nothing
    For Each cell In rng
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then Exit Sub
    Next
    ' if we reached this, all cells are empty
    rng.Value = "x"
End Sub
```